# Why specify the database in the mongodb connection string if you aren't authenticating?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

To connect to MongoDB, you need to use http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/MongoClient.html#.connect.

My question is about specifying the database in the [connection string](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/). It says:

> Optional. The name of the database to authenticate if the connection string includes authentication credentials in the form of username:password@. If /database is not specified and the connection string includes credentials, the driver will authenticate to the admin database.

It seems to me that it's only useful to have the `database` if you also have the `username:password@`. But I've seen examples where the `database` is specified without the `username:password@`. The Node Driver [example itself](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/) uses the string `mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject`.

Why would you ever want to have the `database` without the `username:password@`?

Comment: Otherwise you would need to do an "use" statement any time that you use the connection right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the operation you will do will be done in the database you are choosing.

If you avoid the /database component you need to force it in the code (try to avoid hard coded elements) or you will work in the default database (not a great idea)

Comment: Oh, that seems obvious in retrospect, thanks! How would you "force it in the code"? And do you need to create the database (in the shell?) before connecting to it?

Comment: I think this page will help you https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html